# Python - Count spaces, not blank lines

Tags: python, loops, character

Is there a way to compress a text file and remove the blank lines in order for me to count the spaces in the text? I have a text file of about 20 lines and I want to count the spaces between the words. But I thin I count the white lines as well since i get over 800 in the counter.

```
def spaces():
"""
Counting spaces
"""

number_of_spaces = 0

with open(TEXT, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        space = line.split()
        for i in space:
            for char in i:
                if char.isspace():
                    number_of_spaces += 1

return number_of_spaces
```

Regards

Comment: So, you just don't want to include newline characters in count?

Comment: `line.split()` removes spaces are you sure you get a positive count?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad No, just the spaces between words

Comment: @DanielMesejo I get 852 in the counter and when I gave it a rough count it should be 150-170 spaces between the words.

Comment: @ThomasBengtsson could you provide a small example input and the corresponding output?

Comment: Your `space` list contains words that are extracted from `line` by splitting on spaces, so they contain no space. So, unless your text contains strange characters that `isspace()` would consider as white space while `split()` wouldn't, your function will always return `0`, as it does on the texts I tested it on. So, unless you can provide us with a sample of text that gives a non-zero output for your function, I consider it to be non-reproducible.

Comment: I second @DanielMesejo 's request. We need to know if double white-spaces should be counted, if other whitespace characters like tab stops should be counted etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is count the number of words. Number of spaces are always one less than number of words.

```
def spaces():
number_of_spaces = 0
    with open(TEXT, "r") as fh:
        words = [word for line in fh for word in line.split()]
        number_of_spaces = len(words-1)
return number_of_spaces
```

Comment: Does this count duplicated contiguous spaces?

Comment: But this does count newlines as whitespaces as two lines with two words each will yield three whitespaces, but the text only contains two whitespaces and a newline character.

Comment: I think the OP wants to consider each newline as a whitespace. He might have got the answer he had been looking for from this answer. That's why he had accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions to solve this problem:

```
import re

def spaces(file_name):
    """Return the number of spaces in the text."""
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        return len(re.findall(r' +', f.read()))
```

The regular expression `r' +'` will look for one or more consecutive whitespaces. So double whitespaces are only counted as one. Other whitespace characters like `'\t'` are ignored.

Comment: You cannot pass a file to `findall`. It expects a `string` or `bytes-like` object.

Comment: Good spot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This Below code counts the number of blank spaces and also the number of lines separately.
Hope this helps.

```
import re
count = 0
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname,'r') as f:       #This counts the blank space
    print("Number of space: ", len(re.findall(r' ', f.read())))

with open(fname, 'r') as f:      #This counts the number of lines
    for line in f:
        count += 1
print("Total number of lines is:", (count - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest splitting your lines by spaces and getting your space count as the length of the resulting array minus one?

```
sample_text = """A simple test to see how many
spaces are in these lines of text"""

amount_of_spaces = len(sample_text.split(' ')) - 1
print(amount_of_spaces)
>>> 12
```

This deals well with trailing or multiple subsequent spaces in the text as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the whitespace, why not use regular expressions:

```
import re
amountOfWhitespaces = len(re.findall('\x20', yourString)
print(amountOfWhitespaces)
```

Comment: I think there is no advantage of using the hex value here instead of the more readable `' '`.

Comment: @NOhs There is no disadvantage neither, is there? Depending on how much lines we are talking, I would argue that `' '`loses its readability. ;-)
Also, since the question was not very specific about what white spaces he wants to exclude, I find the additions of hex or code easier than `'[ , , ]'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all white-spaces separately, you can use the inbuilt function `count` of `String`:

```
with open(TEXT, "r") as fh: 
    count = sum(line.strip().count(' ') for line in fh)
```

Note: This does ingore trailing white-spaces etc using `strip`, as you said you only want to count whitespaces between words. It also takes care of empty lines containing whitespaces this way. It counts double white-spaces as two separate white-spaces and it ignores tab characters `'\t'`.

It depends on what you are trying to do, if this is what you indeed want.